# python function multiple return

Tags: python, function, statsmodels

I would like to transform this code to have a function instead :

```
variables = ['oki']              
for var in variables:
    lm_full = sm.formula.ols(formula='%s ~  diag + age + ICVcm3' % var, data=dfwo2).fit()
    print("===============================================================================")
    print("           formule = %s ~ diag + age + ICVcm3" % var)
    print("===============================================================================")
    print(lm_full.summary())
```

At the end I would like something that looks like :

`function(oki,diag,age,ICVcm3,dfwo2)` that would return the result of the loop.

I have no clue of how to do it. The examples that I found on the internet are very basic.... I don't even know what to type on google to get an answer.

Comment: You have to aggregate the *BASIC* results you got over internet and need to modify them as per your requirement.

Comment: Basic pattern for loop returns: start with an accumulator list `result=[]`; `.append()` the result of each iteration to the accumulator in the loop; return `result`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a list of tuples:

```
def myFunction(variables):
    result = []
    for var in variables:
        formula = "           formule = %s ~ diag + age + ICVcm3" % var
        lm_full = sm.formula.ols(formula=formula, data=dfwo2).fit()
        result.append((formula, lm_full.summary()))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

This code shows you how to return the items that have been computed in the function and how to retrieve them in the calling function. Notice how you can return as many, or as few, items as you wish, and that, even if the function returns items your calling code doesn't need you can ignore them. (That's the purpose of the variables named **dummy**.)

I'm using one of the datasets that comes with statsmodels since I don't recognise the one you're using.

```
import statsmodels as sm
df = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Guerry", "HistData").data
df = df[['Lottery', 'Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']].dropna()
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

def regress(variables):
    results = [ ]
    for variable in variables:
        mod = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ %s' % variable, data=df)
        result = mod.fit()
        results . append ( (variable, result.params, result.df_resid, result.rsquared) )
    return results

for result in regress (['Literacy', 'Wealth', 'Region']):
    variable, dummy, dummy, R_squared = result
    print ( variable, R_squared  )
```

Results are like this:

```
Literacy 0.145720612937
Wealth 0.243180384656
Region 0.142107524677
```

Answer (score -1):

your loop is var in variables which only contains 1 item: a string.
So what is the purpose of such a loop anyway? diag,age,ICVcm3,dfwo2 where are all these values delcared? What is the function about? Is seems to be some very specific wierd topic.

Though just guessing, something like this could be what you've been looking for:

```
def myfunction(variables,diag,age,ICVcm3,dfwo2):   
    for var in variables:
        lm_full = sm.formula.ols(formula='%s ~  diag + age + ICVcm3' % var, data=dfwo2).fit()
        print("===============================================================================")
        print("           formule = %s ~ diag + age + ICVcm3" % var)
        print("===============================================================================")
        print(lm_full.summary())
```

Comment: This function does not return the result of the loop. It returns a `None`.